# PostgreSQL stuck on Recovery Mode (strace returns semop)

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql Server with many databases, one of the database got a stucked INSERT INTO and it hangs all the Database. After rebooting the server activates it´s recovery mode, i did a strace and got the following:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "base/14096409", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 755
getdents(755, /* 1024 entries */, 32768) = 32760
getdents(755, /* 1024 entries */, 32768) = 32768
getdents(755, /* 801 entries */, 32768) = 25632
getdents(755, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(755)                              = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "base/14096409", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 755
getdents(755, /* 1024 entries */, 32768) = 32760
getdents(755, /* 1024 entries */, 32768) = 32768
getdents(755, /* 801 entries */, 32768) = 25632
getdents(755, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(755)                              = 0
open("base/14096409", O_RDONLY)         = 755
fsync(755)                              = 0
close(755)                              = 0
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "pg_tblspc", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
getdents(5, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
open("pg_xlog/000000010000004E0000008B", O_RDWR) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "pg_twophase", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 755
getdents(755, /* 2 entries */, 32768)   = 48
getdents(755, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(755)                              = 0
open("base/13702059/13709821", O_RDWR)  = 755
lseek(755, 16384, SEEK_SET)             = 16384
lseek(755, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 32768
write(328, "M\0\0\0\270\372\206w\1\0\4\0008\0\360\1\0 \4 \0\0\0\0 \235\300\5\30\232\n\6"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(755, 8192, SEEK_SET)              = 8192
read(755, "N\0\0\0\20\31\224f\1\0\0\0\374\1\310\22\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0\310\2220\0\330\2370\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(755, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 32768
write(328, "M\0\0\0\340\rQx\1\0\4\0008\0P\1\0 \4 \0\0\0\0(\235\256\5H\232\300\5"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(755, 24576, SEEK_SET)             = 24576
read(755, "N\0\0\0\20\31\224f\1\0\0\0X\0028\21\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0008\221@\0X\2210\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(328, "M\0\0\0 [$y\1\0\4\0008\0X\1\0 \4 \0\0\0\0(\235\254\5H\232\274\5"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(755, 0, SEEK_SET)                 = 0
read(755, "I\0\0\0\310\307\10\t\1\0\0\0000\0\360\37\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0b1\5\0\2\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
semop(3637260, [{12, -1, 0}], 1
```

Any advice what can i do ? Thanks so much !

Comment: From the `strace` I deduce that there are no prepared transactions, so that's not the problem. Can you edit the question and add relevant entries from the log file? Also, it would be nice to hear some more about the problematic insert and the exact behaviour of the database after the restart.

Comment: The whole strace has the same output, only on `base/13702059/13709821` returns that `semop(3637260, [{12, -1, 0}], 1` and got stuck forever. I checked disk space and it´s all fine but still get the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I mean the PostgreSQL database log file, not your strace output.

Comment: Attached: https://ufile.io/nsjdi

Comment: Could you attach to the startup process with `gdb` and [get a stacktrace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD) from it? Please edit the question and add that, it will help figuring out what is wrong.